# Python 3 convert int to dictonary

Tags: python-3.x, int, converters

I want to convert this

```
(554, 334, 24, 15)
```

to

```
[554', ' 334', ' 24', ' 15]
```

If they are a similar question then sorry i didnt find one.

Comment: The first is a malformed `tuple` the second is a malformed `list`... so what do you mean `int` into `dict`? Are these meant to be strings, where are you getting these values from? If you remove the `'`s then converting the `tuple` is as simple as `list(tuple_value)`

Comment: Im using pyautogui to match a pic and then move the mouse to it with. The output from pyautogui is (554, 334, 24, 15) and i only need the first 2 args and i want to delet or ignore the others.

Comment: could you slice the output to get the first two indices? Ex.: `list((554, 334, 24, 15)[0:2])`,  Will return you `[554, 334]`

Comment: You can directly `slice` a `tuple`, e,g, `(554, 334, 24, 15)[:2] == (554, 334)`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list(map(str, list((554, 334, 24, 15)))))

result = ['554', '334', '24', '15']
```

The tuple is converted into a list(), then map() applies the same function to each element of the list, in this case converting the int-type list elements to a string, the resulting list after this conversion is then printed.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)